# Why is the "mark as unread" button greyed out in some emails in my Gmail application?

Tags: gmail, android-12, google-pixel-6

Why is the "mark as unread" button greyed out in some emails in my Gmail application?

Example;

[image]

I use Pixel 6 + Android 12.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.